# DJANGO REST FRAMEWORK IMAGE UPLOAD ["The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form."]

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, base64

I can't seem to upload an image to my project.

I always get this error when I try to submit the form from the frontend :

```
["The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form."]
```

I've found some answers regarding the base64 encoding of the image but I can't seem to get it to work.

Any help would be much appreciated!!

thanks

here is the source code:

### Models:

```py
class Person(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    age = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    dob = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Details(models.Model):
    
    party = models.ForeignKey(Person,on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    related_name='party_details',null=True,blank=True)
    adress = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    arrival= models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.adress
```

### Serializers:

```py
class DetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Details
        # fields='__all__'
        fields = ('id','party','adress','date','arrival')


class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    party_details =DetailsSerializer(many=True)
    


    class Meta:
        model = Person
        # fields='__all__'
        fields = ('id','name','age','dob','image','party_details')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        named_details = validated_data.pop('party_details')
        details = Person.objects.create(**validated_data) 
        for named_detail in named_details:
            Details.objects.create(party=details, ** named_detail)
        return details     
    
    def update(self,instance, validated_data):
        named_details = validated_data.pop('party_details')
        details = (instance.party_details).all()  
        details = list(details)
    
        instance.name = validated_data.get('name', instance.name) 
        instance.age = validated_data.get('age', instance.age)
        instance.dob = validated_data.get('dob', instance.dob)
        instance.image = validated_data.get('image', instance.image)
        instance.save()

        for named_detail in named_details:
            detail = details.pop(0)
            detail.adress = named_detail.get('adress',detail.adress)
            detail.date = named_detail.get('date',detail.date)
            detail.arrival = named_detail.get('arrival', detail.arrival)
            detail.save()
        return instance
```

### views:

```py
class ListAllPerson (generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset=Person.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PersonSerializer


class ListPerson (generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = PersonSerializer
    queryset= Person.objects.all()


class ListAllDetails(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
        queryset=Details.objects.all()
        serializer_class = DetailsSerializer

class ListDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = DetailsSerializer
    queryset=Details.objects.all()


class CreateDetail(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
        queryset=Details.objects.all()
        serializer_class = DetailsSerializer
```

### HTML FORM and Axios:

```
const profileImage = async ()=>{
   let formField = new FormData()
formField.append('image',addImages)

    await axios({
      method: 'patch',
      url: url,
      data: formField


    }).then((response) => {

      history.push('/')
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    })

}
     



<div className="add-image-input">
 <form action="" className="add-image-form">
 <input className="image-input" value={addImages} 
   onChange={(e)=>{setAddImages(e.target.value)}} type="file"/>
  <button className="" type="button" onClick={profileImage} >add</button>
  </form>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully you are using React js, this should help. At the point of
saving and submitting your form data, your function should look like this:

```js
const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data)
    let form_data = new FormData();
    form_data.append('upload_image_photo', data.cover_image, data.cover_image.name);
    form_data.append('title', data.title);
    form_data.append('category', data.category);
    form_data.append('price_per_night', data.price_per_night);
    form_data.append('room_slug', data.room_slug);
    form_data.append('capacity', data.capacity);
    form_data.append('room_size', data.room_size);
    let url = '/url to the end point you are saving with the expected image field / ';
    const config = {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
    };
    axios.post(url, form_data, config)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res.request.status);
            console.log(res.data);
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
};
```